# How to remove previous active classes in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am make a list and in the list when I click it toggles class `active`  but previous elements still contains `active` class when I click on different element

```
<ul>
    <li class="click_me">Here </li>
    <li class="click_me">Here </li>
    <li class="click_me">Here </li>
    <li class="click_me">Here </li>
</ul>

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.click_me').click(function()
    {
        $.each(function()
        {
            $('.click_me').toggleClass('active');
        });
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });
});

<style>
.active
{
    background-color: red;
}
</style>
```

What I want is that when I click on different `li` element previous `li`'s `active` class must be toggled out. Sorry for poor english!
I tried to add each loop but it didn't work.

Comment: `$('.active').removeClass('active');`

Comment: OMG! YES IT DID WORK! THank you both of you

Comment: I removed each loop and put removeClass instead of toggle so thanks to both of you

Comment: `$('.click_me.active').removeClass('active');` if you're using the `.active` class on other type of elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. It should work! All answers work!

```
$('.click_me').click(function()
{
    $('.click_me.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

To get this to work you simply need to remove the `.active` class from any elements that already have it, excluding the current element, which should be toggled. Try this:

```js
$('.click_me').click(function() {
  $('.active').not(this).removeClass('active');
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="click_me">Here</li>
  <li class="click_me">Here</li>
  <li class="click_me">Here</li>
  <li class="click_me">Here</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

### The correct way is to use [event-delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/):

```js
$('ul').on('click', '.click_me', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');   // <--- The trick!
})
```

```css
.active{ background:lightblue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="click_me active">Click here</li>
  <li class="click_me">Click here</li>
  <li class="click_me">Click here</li>
  <li class="click_me">Click here</li>
</ul>
```

That should do it!

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

Remove the class from all the li elements excluding the clicked element and toggle class on clicked element.

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.click_me').click(function()
    {       
        $("li.active").not(this).removeClass('active');
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
    });
});
```

```css
.active
{
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="click_me">Here </li>
    <li class="click_me">Here </li>
    <li class="click_me">Here </li>
    <li class="click_me">Here </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.click_me').click(function()
{
    // remove the .active class from all the .active elements.
    $('.click_me.active').removeClass('active');
    // add it to this one
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```